# BGA rework - Help needed

Tags: soldering, bga, solder-mask, rework, gan

I've just started working on a PCB with BGA components (EPC GaN HEMT devices, plus BGA gate drives), and my attempts at assembly, have been quite frustrating.

I'm using a heat plate (set to 150 degrees), and a hot air gun moving from 200->240->260C as I've seen in one application note. Some components inevitably don't get assembled properly, and I have to perform rework. I'm trying to make the BGA pads leveled by throwing a small amount of flux on them, and then a flat tip soldering iron over a solder wick to suck the solder out.

But, it always ends up removing some of my soldermask, making a good assembly even harder. Has anyone have experience and can share a tip or two on how to do this work? I'm attaching a photo of my scrapped off soldermask on the PCB for reference.
[image]

Comment: It’s not an answer, but invest yourself a nice reflow oven. Had to learn this myself, the even spread of heat is gold. I use a IR oven with a ventilator (low air exchange). And I always use ENIG instead of HASL. Good solderpaste, like from GC, T4.

Comment: @RemyHx, yes I should use an oven instead. But even with an oven, if a bga component fails, how do you tend to replace it with a new one?

Comment: Removal: hot plate. Kapton tape on neighboring components. Hot air removal of bga. Clean the pads afterwards, flux and reflow back in the oven. Most components can be reflowed once or twice.

Comment: @RemyHx and the remaining solder on the pads in the PCB, it doesn't cause any problems? Also would you recommend solid or liquid flux?

Comment: I think you could try to remove with desolder tape. Also depends a lot if the pads are small or very small. To be honest for a BGA i would choose to just sacrifice te board.